# Trying to add textbox values as a table row

Tags: javascript, textbox

I´m trying to read 3 textbox values: first name, last name and age, and adding them after clicking the save button as a row in a table, but it isn't working. What's wrong with my function?

```
function save()
{ 
var firstName= document.getElementById("txtFname").value;
var lastName=document.getElementById("txtLname").value;
var ageValue=parseInt(document.getElementById("age").value,10);

var table2=document.getElementById("dbtable");
var fNameValue= value.createTextNode(firstName);
var lNameValue= value.createTextNode(lastName);
var agetextnode=value.createTextNode(ageValue);

td1=document.createElement("td");
td2=document.createElement("td");
td3=document.createElement("td");

td1.appendChild(fNameValue);
td2.appendChild(lNameValue);
td3.appendChild(agetextnode);

tr1=document.createElement("tr");
tr1.appendChild(td1);
tr1.appendChild(td2);
tr1.appendChild(td3);

table2.appendChild(tr1);
}
```

Comment: What's `firstname`, `lastname`, `ageValue` and `value` variable? Where are they defined? Did you check your console for errors?

Comment: sorry , i forgot to put them in my question but i wrote them in my code anyway:

        var firstName= document.getElementById("txtFname").value;
        var lastName=document.getElementById("txtLname").value;

Comment: Could you also add your HTML? Where does the value variable come from? ( value.createTextNode )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps if you can provide the full HTML/JavaScript being used so we can see where the issue is.

I would also recommend spreading out your logic to make it easier to troubleshoot. You essentially have 3 steps:

1. Obtain the entered values
2. Generate the markup for the new row
3. Append the row to the table

Here's an example how those could look with your requirements.

```js
function save () {
  const age = document.getElementById('age').value;
  const first = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
  const last = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
  const tbody = document.querySelector('#dtable tbody');
  tbody.appendChild(createRow(age, first, last));
}

function createRow(age, first, last) {
  const tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tr.appendChild(createTd(age));
  tr.appendChild(createTd(first));
  tr.appendChild(createTd(last));
  return tr;
}

function createTd(value) {
  const td = document.createElement('td');
  td.innerText = value;
  return td;
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="age" placeholder="age" />
<input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" />
<input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" />
<button onclick="save()">Save</button>

<table id="dtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>First</th>
      <th>Last</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i posted it below can you check it please

Comment: Please upvote or mark as answer if this helps. Otherwise, be more clear on what your question is. The above code fulfills your requirements